# Bootstrap navigation menu doesn't seem to be responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made this simple navigation menu & I have used Bootstrap elements to make it responsive but the problem is ,it's not responsive at all!

Here's my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div><!-- Navbar Header -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="BJadidBold" style="font-size:25px;"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="BJadidBold" style="font-size:25px;"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="BJadidBold" style="font-size:25px;"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="BJadidBold" style="font-size:25px;"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="BJadidBold" style="font-size:25px;"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>               
        </div>
    </div><!-- End Container -->
</nav><!-- End Navbar -->
```

Can u guys tell me what's going wrong ? thx...

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code in bootply and it's working properly!!
First check, Did you load all bootstrap library properly??
bootply [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/8DPxaVLwRg#)

load Following type of file:
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div><!-- Navbar Header -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="BJadidBold" style="font-size:25px;"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="BJadidBold" style="font-size:25px;"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="BJadidBold" style="font-size:25px;"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="BJadidBold" style="font-size:25px;"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="BJadidBold" style="font-size:25px;"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>               
        </div>
    </div><!-- End Container -->
</nav><!-- End Navbar -->

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```